# String operations not working on python strings

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am using xlrd to read xls cell into a string, after which none of the string functions work on that string.

```
attribute_name = str(worksheet.cell_value(row,col))
attribute_name.strip()
attribute_name.lower()
print len(attribute_name)
if(len(attribute_name) > 8):
    print 'value' + str(ord(attribute_name[8]))
    print 'attributename:'+attribute_name+':'
```

prints :

```
9
value32
attributename:TSA01_HE :
9
value32
attributename:TSA02_HE :
```

I am mainly interested in getting rid of the whitespace at the end of the attribute name.  Am I missing anything obvious ? I have tried replace etc but as you can see, even .lower() doesnt work.

$ python --version
Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 2):

`strip` and `lower` do not work in place; they return the changed value. So you should assign their result to the old variable.

```
attribute_name = attribute_name.strip().lower()
```

Answer (score 2):

Methods like `str.XXX` always return new strings instead of edit the original string. This is because strings are immutables in python. Likewise, operators on string like `+=` rebinds the variable to a new string as well:

```
In [755]: s='a'

In [756]: id(s)
Out[756]: 30887376

In [757]: s+='bc' #same as s=s+'bc'

In [758]: id(s) #identity of the variable has been changed
Out[758]: 301145192
```

So if you wish your operation on a string to take effect, always remember to assign the result back with `=`.

Other immutables like `int`s, `float`s, `tuple`s, `frozenset`s works the same as `str`s. E.g., you won't expect `i=3; i.__add__(10)` makes `i==13`.

Answer (score 0):

Take care that both `strip()` and `lower()` do not modify the string you apply them on; you should therefore do `attribute_name = attribute_name.strip().lower()`.

Example:

```
>>> a = '   A   '
>>> a.strip().lower()
'a'
>>> a
'   A   '
```